# Associate a number to each line in bash

Tags: bash

How do I use a bash for loop to append a number to each entry? What I tried was the following:

```
for var in $(cat tmp), i in {1..7}; do echo $var:$i >> days_of_week; done

Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

I am looking for this output here:

```
Monday:1
Tuesday:2
Wednesday:3
Thursday:4
Friday:5
Saturday:6
Sunday:7
```

Answer (score 3):

In Bash:

```
n=0
while IFS= read -r day; do
    printf "%s:%d\n" "$day" $((++n))
done < days_of_week
```

This reads the names from the file and appends a counter after incrementing it (the `$((++n))` part).

Or awk:

```
$ awk '{print $0 ":" NR}' days_of_week 
Monday:1
Tuesday:2
Wednesday:3
Thursday:4
Friday:5
Saturday:6
Sunday:7
```

`$0` is the complete record (line in this case), the `NR` is the "record number", which in this case is the same as the line number.

Comment: In awk command why $0 and what is NR? How does it know to start at 1 and end at 7?

Comment: @power_output I've added a little explanation.

Comment: For the while loop-- the IFS, -r and printf aren't needed.  It's much simpler without them and using echo.

Comment: The while loop is an improvement of the for-loop (not important for your current inputfile), the `++n` is a replacement of your counter `i`. Be safe and start with `n=0` (before the `while`-loop).

Comment: @SaintHax `IFS=` and `read -r` might not be required for this specific input example, but are very much a good practice any time you read a file and don't want to modify whitespace and lose backslashes. `echo` is not reliably portable and POSIX [encourages](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) the use of `printf` instead. I don't agree with this being much more  complicated, but it is much more robust.

Comment: @WalterA I think our work experience differs then-- I read the OP as the requirements, and it seems in this case it would not be beneficial to preserve white spaces-- actually, detremental.  Nor do I see a chance of escape characters-- granted I work in a shop of about 100 servers, all on 3 flavors of Linux, so simplicity (for 3rd shift Ops) is more important to me than portability.

Comment: @SaintHax The OP's requirements are simplified. He already succeeded in adding the numbers 1 .. 7 in his question, so I think he just has presented a minimal case for his more complex real-life situation. Just get used to wearing a safety belt in the car, also for 200 innocent metres.

Answer (score 1):

I would number the lines with `cat -n` then reformat the output with `sed` :

```
cat -n tmp | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)\s(.*)/\2:\1/'
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of high levelof what is done? What is the difference between '/' and '\' in that command? what os 's'?

Comment: It can be a little bit much depending on your knowledge of regular expressions in general and sed in particular. I can at least give you a global view, tell me if you want more info in a particular direction : I'm using sed to run a `s`ubstitution command, of which one format is `s/pattern/replacement/`. Here I match a number at the start of a line in a group, then the rest of the line in another ; this matches `cat -n`'s format. Finally Iuse back-references in the replacement pattern to invert these groups and join them with a ":".

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple one, just increment a counter.  Initialize the counter, read each line, and tack on the counter before incrementing it.

```
i=1; while read day; do
   echo $day:$i
   ((i++))
done <tmp >>days_of_week
```

if you really are set on a for loop

```
i=1; for day in $(cat tmp); do
   echo $day:$i
   ((i++))
done >>days_of_week
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print $0 ":" NR}' << EOF > days_of_week
> Monday
> Tuesday
> Wednesday
> Thursday
> Friday
> Saturday
> Sunday
> EOF
$ cat days_of_week
Monday:1
Tuesday:2
Wednesday:3
Thursday:4
Friday:5
Saturday:6
Sunday:7
```